# Chrome console (F12) doesn't show up

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools

Suddenly my Chrome console can't show up any more. I even tried to uninstall and install Chrome, but nothing helps.

Look how it looks without the console:

[image]

And this is how it looks when I press <kbd>F12</kbd> to open the console (the same thing if I try to open it via the menu) notice that it pushes the content aside with blankspace and there isn't any console at all!:

[image]

Comment: Try starting chrome with the flag `--disable-extensions`. Also, what build number / version of Chrome are you using?

Comment: That, and try nuking your User Profile instead of reinstalling.

Comment: How is this a question for Stack Overflow ? Its a site for Q&A about programming, not for Chrome-Support.

Comment: @DatRid This has to do with a programming tool, so it is [on-topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: @Xan Thanks, didn't knew that this is also on-topic, seems like I overlooked it, my fault, sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest you to try this:

- Go to %LOCALAPPDATA%\Google\Chrome\User Data\
- Rename the folder "Default" to "Backup" or something else
- Launch Chrome (it will recreate the Default folder with a blank user profile)

If you don't have any problem after doing this, your user profile is corrupted. When you uninstall Chrome, your user profile is kept, this is why the problem was still here after reinstalling.

Comment: Thanks it worked, but it means i'll have to lose my profile, which folder in the profile may be the corrupted one?

Comment: Get your old profile (the broken one) back and try to clean Chrome with a software like Adwcleaner (http://general-changelog-team.fr/en/tools/15-adwcleaner). I can't guarantee it will work, but this software works on my PC for similar problems with Chrome.

You can also just get your bookmarks back (if you don't need your history, passwords, etc...). It's the safest way.

Answer (score 37):

<kbd>F Lock</kbd> also disables this functionality. Please toggle the F lock state and check.

[image]

Comment: Flock indeed :-)

Comment: Only on some laptops. What is this one?

Comment: Thank you a lot. I spent several hours to find out why my function keys doesn't work. It is really useless and dangerous feature.

Answer (score 9):

If your <kbd>F12</kbd> press alone doesn't open the devtools in the browser then press and hold <kbd>Fn</kbd> and then press <kbd>Esc</kbd>. It's done!!

Now you will be able to open devtool just by pressing <kbd>F12</kbd>.

Comment: This one was the fix I needed.  Thanks!

Comment: Re *"hold Fn"*: Only on some laptops. What is this one?

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar problem. In my case, it was the TrackIR software intercepting <kbd>F12</kbd>. So if you have TrackIR, check it is not running.

Comment: Thanks for this, almost 2 years later and yep, TrackIR was still running.  That's what I get for doing development and gaming on the same machine!

Answer (score 0):

I just stumbled upon this and fixed it by turning off all extensions, and then turning them back on one by one. It turns out in my case the screen reader extension "Chrome Vox" caused the issue.